# Swift. How can I create own initializer for cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a class `FbPostViewCell` which inherits a `UITableViewCell` class. From `FbPostViewCell` I makes other classes: `FbLinkPostViewCell`. How can I init `FbPostViewCell` substance of `FbLinkPostViewCell` object in specific manner? I mean I need to init members of `FbPostViewCell` instance of `FbLinkPostViewCell` object.

I wrote a `convenience init() { super.init() /* stuff */ }` but program behaviour showed to me that my members weren't initialized. Same situation with `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) /* same stuff */ }`. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you have added stored properties to your subclass you will have to initiate them in some way. This means you should either:
- Make all added properties optional, this way they can stay without value
- Give all properties an initial value
- Add a custom initializer

this custom initializer should be just a regular init which calls super.init() and initializes all the properties. If you have added this init you can always create an object of your subclass type by initiating with your own convenience initializer. But this convenience initializer should call self.init().

Hope this helps, relevant page in Apple Swift guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203

EDIT:

```
class FbPostViewCell : UITableViewCell {
   init(maybe variables) {
      super.init() //inits UITableViewCell properties
      /* init fbpostviewcell properties with 'maybe variables' */
   }
}

class FbLinkPostViewCell : FbPostViewCell {
   init(more variables) {
      super.init(maybe variables) //inits UItvc properties and fbpostviewcell's
      /* init fblinkpostviewcells properties with more variables */
   }

   convenience init(postMode?) {
      if let mode = postMode {
         switch mode {
         case mode1: self.init(mode1 specific vars)
         case mode2: self.init(mode2 speciific vars)
         default: self.init(default vars)
      }
      else {
         self.init(no mode vars)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: My properties are outlets. Is there a way to initialise outlets with my requirements? I mean `text` property in UILabels and `image` in UIImage.

> "If you have added this init you can always create an object of your subclass type by initiating with your own convenience initializer." How ?? :)

Comment: @drewpts I added an example, forgive me syntactical errors and stuff I am not close to a Mac atm. Hope this helps